Any reference about these topics (waves on the sphere)?
At the end of the section 1.9.2 in the book A Panoramic View of Riemannian Geometry, it has the following text about waves on the sphere:
"We will not say much now about spherical harmonics ... For those who like recent results and open problems ... we mention first that Yves Meyer says among other things the following. We consider the wave equation on spheres ... as, for example, describing the evolution with time of a thin layer of water on the sphere. This would describe the motion of the sea, if there were no continents on the planet. ... His first result backs intuition. Disturb the water with a big shock (a Dirac distribution, if you prefer) somewhere, say at the north pole. Then you will always find another big shock at the south pole after a time T which is no larger than 2π. But Meyer’s second series of results oppose intuition: the big shock can move from the north to the south pole while remaining extremely small everywhere for all time between 0 and T, as in figure 1.102 on the next page. Worse: some apparently moderate shocks can, with larger and larger time, be very small almost everywhere and almost all the time, but at some times and some places can be as big as desired (everything there and then will break down). Meyer’s results explained the following strange observation: quite recently a tidal wave was observed at Martinique, and came back there later, this being completely unnoticed everywhere else in between times."
I'm interested in Yves Meyer's two results mentioned above. So my questions are:

Is there any introductory reference about these two results (or more general topics)?
Is there any more advanced reference about these two results (or more general topics)?

